# Displaying figure multiple times with matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, figure

Is it possible to display a single figure multiple times in matplotlib?

I am looking for a solution that can roughly resemble the following:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

ax1.imshow(a)
ax2.imshow(b)

fig1.show()
fig2.show()
fig1.show()
```

This seems to work in IDLE, figures stay active until closed and I can type in IDLE to open a new figure while the old one is still active. This does not work though when I run the script. Does this have anything to do with the interactive mode?

I also tried to pause the plot when running the script:

```
fig1.show()
plt.pause(10)
```

but this displays immediately both figures. Why is IDLE capable of displaying fig1.show() and waiting till it's closed, but while running the script fig1.show() closes immediately unless paused? And why does it display all the figures at the same time instead of just the one instance?

Answer (score -1):

If you run matplotlib inside, for example ipython, you should use `fig1.show()` to show the figure and at the same time avoid blocking the ipython terminal.  However if you want to run the script from a cmd, i.e. with `python script.py`, you should instead use `plt.show()` (note that it's enough with `plt.show()` once even if you have multiple figures), which will keep the figures up.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, however my main question was concerning something else.

While running in the script mode (i.e. python script.py), can I display the same figure twice with plt.show()? My point was that I can do that in interactive mode with fig.show(). Is there a way to do that in a script?